# Handle tab change on when having multiple MatTabGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

To be able to enable/disable some email templates I've divided my select-tabs into different groups.

Please see stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddysaa

Initially, all tabs are set to index 0. If I first go to **index 3 in group 1**, then **index 2 in group 2**, then back to **index 3 in Group 1**, the selectedTabChange-handler isn't triggered.

The cause for this is that when I go back to group 1 and visit index 3 **again** this isn't read as a tabChange, of course.

I've tried to handle this by resetting each groups' `selectedIndex` to 0 every time there's a group change, but this doesn't work. I can't understand why this doesn't work.

Is this the correct workaround for doing this? If so - what am I missing? 
Is there any other way to handle template groups to get the same behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (click) rather than (selectedTabChange)
It should work your purpose

```
 <mat-card class="email-template-card">
        <mat-card-content class="email-template-card-content">
            <!-- Standard email templates -->
            <mat-tab-group [ngClass]="activeGroup != 0 ? 'mat-no-ink-bar': ''"
                (click)="group_1_tabChanged($event,selectedGroup_1_Tab.value)" [selectedIndex]="selectedGroup_1_Tab.value">
                <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of group_1_TemplateList" [label]=(tab)>
                </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>

            <!-- PDMR email templates -->
            <mat-tab-group [ngClass]="activeGroup != 1 ? 'mat-no-ink-bar': ''" (click)="group_2_tabChanged($event,selectedGroup_2_Tab.value)" 
                [selectedIndex]="selectedGroup_2_Tab.value" *ngIf="group_2_TemplateList.length > 0">
                <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab2 of group_2_TemplateList" [label]=(tab2)>
                </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>

            <!-- Sensitive email templates -->
            <mat-tab-group [ngClass]="activeGroup != 3 ? 'mat-no-ink-bar': ''"
            (click)="group_3_tabChanged($event,selectedGroup_3_Tab.value)" [selectedIndex]="selectedGroup_3_Tab.value"
                *ngIf="group_3_TemplateList.length > 0">
                <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab4 of group_3_TemplateList" [label]=(tab4)>
                </mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>
            <!-- <div class="ngx-editor">
                    <ckeditor class="ngx-editor" height="500px" resizer="none" [config]="ckConfig"
                        [(ngModel)]="templateInfo.content" [spellcheck]="true"></ckeditor>
                </div>-->

                <h1>{{templateInfo}}</h1>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work. When using click-event I'm missing the index which will be collected from ```MatTabChangeEvent```

Comment: pass the value in the parameters, you will get the index aswell

Comment: (click)="group_3_tabChanged($event,selectedGroup_3_Tab.value)" like this

Comment: Aah that did it, thank you very much!! Would you please update your answer with that and I'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

First you need `(slectedIndexChange)` and `(click)` in `<mat-tab-group>`. Change in in first mat-tab-group here.. like this..

```
<mat-tab-group [ngClass]="activeGroup != 0 ? 'mat-no-ink-bar': ''"
        (selectedTabChange)="group_1_tabChanged($event)"
        (selectedIndexChange)="group_1_tabChanged($event)" 
        [selectedIndex]="selectedGroup_1_Tab.value" 
        (click)="alert($event)">
        <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of group_1_TemplateList"  [label]=(tab)>
        </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

You click event is...

```
alert(value){
   this.templateInfo = `re Click of Group1 index is : ${this.activeGroup}`
}
```

by this, way you can get index of cliked selected tab. and by array index you can get name of that tab.

Comment: Tried this, and unfortunately, it's still a problem that the other, not-clicked, groups' values arent reset.